# Syncing files between projects/buckets in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I am trying to synchronize files between two projects and two buckets on Google Cloud.

However, I would like to only copy files that are not in `A` but not in `B` (destination). It is fine to overwrite files that are both in `A` and `B` (preferred).

When I do the following:

- in my bucket, I create a folder `test` and add the folder `A` with inside `file-1`
- I run the following command: `gsutil cp -r gs://from-project.appspot.com/test gs://to-project.appspot.com/test2`

This works fine, and I have the folder `A` within the folder `test2` in my to-project bucket.

Then the problem occurs:

- I add a folder `B` and within folder `A` I delete `file-1` and add `file-2` (to test the notion of a file is in `A` but not in `B`).
- When I run the same command however, I do not get that only `file-2` gets copied and I have an additional folder `B`, but instead I get a new folder within `test2` named `test` where inside I find `A` and `B` but without `file-1` in `a` (basically a replica of the new situation).

[image]

Why does this happen and how can I prevent this to enable the syncing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`gsutil rsync`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) command is preferred to synchronize content of two buckets.

You can use the `-d` option to delete files under your destination bucket that have been not found under the source bucket. Be careful though, because it can delete files in the destination bucket.

Comment: It's now [gcloud storage rsync](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage/rsync) but annoyingly the sync happens via the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

In each bucket there is a transfer data object with which you can create storage transfer jobs. [The docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-to-cloud-storage) say use that for 1TB above but seems to work just fine for small data and won't copy data locally.

[image]